# Using diff drive to drive a new robot

Tags: gazebo, differential-drive, sdf, ubuntu, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to make a model of my own robot and plugins. However, I can't drive the robot. Moreover,the information is not being published into /gz/cmd_vel or /gazebo/cmd_vel or /gz/odom topics.

Here is the header of my model.sdf

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.4">
  <model name="myrobot">
    <link name="chassis">
      <pose>0 0 .1 0 0 0</pose>
```

Here are the plugins of my model.sdf

```
<plugin name="modelplugin" filename="libmyrobot_sonar_model_plugin.so"/>
<plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>10</updateRate>
            <leftJoint>left_wheel_hinge</leftJoint>
            <rightJoint>right_wheel_hinge</rightJoint>
            <wheelSeparation>0.5380</wheelSeparation>
            <wheelDiameter>0.2410</wheelDiameter>
            <torque>20</torque>
            <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
            <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
            <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
            <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
            <robotNamespace>gz</robotNamespace>
 </plugin>
    ...
```

I don't understand these parameters, anything else except  seems right for my robot. Can anybody explain what should I write in robotBaseFrame tag.

What should I to drive the robot? Do I need any other plugin? Any answer will be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68599/using-diff-drive-to-drive-a-new-robot/) by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

-update rate -> frequency in (Hz) of publishing by the plugin
-leftJoint -> specify the name of the joint connecting left wheel of your differential drive robot to the chassis
-wheelSeparation -> distance between the 2 wheels in a diff drive robot
-commandTopic ->name of the
-topic on which you can publish the linear and angular velocity of the robot
-odometryTopic -> Topic on which you can subscribe to the
-odometry data. robotNameSpace ->  (generally the name of the robot... i am not sure)

---

Originally posted by [keshav_sarraf](https://answers.ros.org/users/18286/keshav_sarraf/) with karma: 66 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) on 2015-08-19**:
Hi! Can you confirm that the wheelSeparation is specified in meters?